# Spring boot api call return 404 not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

when I'm trying to make an API call to the API I created with Spring Boot, I get the following error message.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2024-02-20T23:08:57.739+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource api/players/get.\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:585)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:52)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)\r\n",
    "message": "No static resource api/players/get.",
    "path": "/api/players/get"
}
```

Here is my Controller file

```
package com.nbastats.nbabackend.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.nbastats.nbabackend.entity.Player;
import com.nbastats.nbabackend.service.PlayerService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;



@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/players")
public class PlayerController {
    @Autowired
    private PlayerService playerService;
    
    public PlayerController(PlayerService playerService) {
        this.playerService = playerService;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/get")
    public List<Player> getPlayers(
        @RequestParam(required = false) String player_name,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String position,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String team
    ) {
        if (team != null && position != null) {
            return playerService.getPlayersByTeamAndPosition(team, position);
        } else if (team != null) {
            return playerService.getPlayersFromTeam(team);
        } else if (player_name != null) {
            return playerService.getPlayersByName(player_name);
        } else if (position != null) {
            return playerService.getPlayersByPosition(position);
        } else {
            return playerService.getPlayers();
        }
    }
}
```

edit:
main class

```
package com.nbastats.nbabackend;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.nbastats.NbaBackendApplication.controller","com.nbastats.NbaBackendApplication.repository"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.nbastats.NbaBackendApplication"})
public class NbaBackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NbaBackendApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/nba_stats
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = postgres

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate,dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

I believe I am setting up the API path correctly, not sure why the api is not found.

I tried removing "path=" but get the same error.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@GetMapping(path = "get")` (without the leading `/`)

Comment: Can you show your main class (including its `package` declaration) and your `application.properties`?

Comment: just added my main class and `application.properties` to the post

Comment: Any reason for using @ComponentScan? Spring should automatically detect everything if they're placed inside `org/example/<project-name>/` . Everything else looks as it should. Can you post an image of what your project directory looks like?

Comment: before I was getting `bean of type service not found error` when trying to run the spring boot application and adding @ComponentScan was the fix. Now that you mentioned it, I just removed the @ComponentScan and everything is working properly now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Normally is not necessary to use `@ComponentScan` annotation to recognize repositories and controllers, so something weird or wrong is happening in your project configuration.

But about this issue... Seems like there are some typos in your package declaration for the `@ComponentScan`.

As I see on your controller file, your `@ComponentScan` must be: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.nbastats.nbabackend.controller", "com.nbastats.nbabackend.repository"})`

Notice that is `nbabackend` instead of `NbaBackendApplication`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing @ComponentScan fixed the issue. All my API calls are going through properly now.